# Is is appropriate to approach the company owner with a business idea?

Tags: united-kingdom, technology, tech-industry

I work for a company in the UK in a technology-based industry that's only a few years old. The company is fairly young and the owner takes and active role within the company - so I see him fairly often.

This company is not his first and as I understand it from the employees who have been around longer than I have the owner has a real eye for new business ideas and has been highly successful in recent times (meaning he has the money).

I've had a business idea in an unrelated tech-based industry and I'm wondering if it's appropriate to approach the owner with this idea asking for funds?

He has given funds (and office space) to ideas (of his own) in the past.

Comment: If you do it, be prepared and respectful of his time before you present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's appropriate but you need to remember something. He's your employer. That means whatever idea you give to him, he will take as his own. And at least in the United States, it would almost certainly belong to his company legally. I'm not sure whether that would be the case where you are.

I would instead advise discussing your ideas with someone you know who doesn't have a conflict of interest like your boss does.

Comment: I followed this advice and we weren't able to refine the idea enough to make it worth putting forward. Accepted as an answer.